# JPA get entity from DB and not from Cache

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation where i get entity from database and do some changes on it. Before saving i want to get old entity from DB, but what ever i try it gets me that changed entity from cache. I tried writing HQL, writing native queries but result is the same since he first save entity and then get it ??!?! I tried also :

```
entityManager.refresh(entity);
```

But then both old and new entity get refreshed and i lose my  changes.

I am using spring JPA and hibernate 2nd level cache.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not possible. You will have to copy your entity object before doing any changes to the managed instance if you need both states for comparison.